# How to fill a javafx line graph with array using loop?

Tags: javafx-8

I want to fill a line graph in javafx using for loop. At every iteration it should plot the line as per the value in array of integers.

Answer (score 0):

You will already have found the solution. But here you go (I assume you have a `List<Integer[]> arrayList`):

```
//Defining X axis  
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();

//Defining y axis 
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

//Make LineChart
LineChart linechart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);

//Make List to save your XYChartSeries
List<XYChart.Series> seriesList = new ArrayList<>();

//Iterate over your Data
for (Integer[] integers : arrayList) {

  XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
  for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
     Integer integer = integers[i];
     series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, integer));
  }
  seriesList.add(series);
  linechart.getData().add(seriesList.get(seriesList.size() - 1));
}
```